# Image resizing to be done programatically or taken care by model config file in tensorflow?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, machine-learning-model

For Deep Learning using Tensorflow, is it necessary to resize the images to a predefined width and height before before training using a model?
     OR

In model configuration file , I noticed this snippet? Does this mean all training images are resized automatically by tesorflow ?

```
  image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 600
        max_dimension: 1024
      }
```

My positive training site has varied sizes..

corners_40N1_0.jpg 323*283

corners_40N1_1.jpg 318*271

corners_40N1_2.jpg 341*306

corners_40N1_3.jpg 318*329

corners_45O16_0.jpg 250*280

Negative training data are of equal size.
56K7NE_80.jpg 360*360

56K7NE_81.jpg 360*360

56K7NE_82.jpg 360*360

56K7NE_83.jpg 360*360

56K7NE_84.jpg 360*360